# What do I get after fetch and how deal with it

Tags: javascript, fetch

After request I have response in a body and it looks like [{...}]. In my browser console it is noticed as array. But console.log(users[0]) is interpreted as undefined. Why can't I get the first element of users object?

```
    async function getUsers() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/users");
    const users = await response.json();
    return users;
}

let users = getUsers();
console.log(users[0]);
console.log(users);
```

Comment: `let users =  await getUsers();`

Comment: As a side-note, you can remove the `await` before `response.json()`.

Answer (score 5):

what you get after fetch is a promise

You deal with it asynchronously by using .then

```
getUsers().then((users) => {
    console.log(users[0]); //returns the user with in the first index
    console.log(users); // returns all users
});
```

Comment: That means I can not save it to some variable?

Comment: Of course you can. You can declare users outside the scope and the you do something like.     let users = users    Inside the function

Answer (score 1):

> getUsers returns Promise, try using then

`getUsers().then((users) => {console.log(users[0]);console.log(users);});`

Comment: So I can not save my fetch result in some variable as array for example?

Comment: @evggenn why couldn't you? `then((users) => {results_array[0] = users;})`

Answer (score 1):

After a fetch you get a promise, which has states like pending, reject, resolve, therefore you get a promise after getUsers, and you can use .then on the returned value

```
getUsers().then((users) => {
  let users = users
  setUsers(users)
  console.log(users[0]);
  console.log(users);
});
```

This return the users in a console.